# How to send data to custom network?

Tags: polkadot-js, custom-rpc

is there any simple example to **send data to network**?

like name, email, phone, address (which is made keyring), and address, etc

Answer (score 1):

In Substrate you have the [pallet identity](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/identity/README.md):

> Enables a federated naming system that allows multiple registrars to be added from a specified origin. Registrars can set a fee to provide identity-verification service.

It has an extrinsic [set_identity](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/identity/src/lib.rs#L330) that associates the identity of an account. (You can see the struct IdentityInfo [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/identity/src/types.rs#L290)).

This pallet exists in Polkadot, so you can store data associated to an account there. If you want to do it in your custom network you can integrate that pallet in your network. Take an example about how the Polkadot runtime is configured to use this pallet [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/runtime/polkadot/src/lib.rs#L626).

And finally as you added the tag `Polkadot-js` in order to set the identity  using this tool: `api.tx.identity.setIdentity`.

Check the [docs](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/extrinsics/#setidentityinfo-palletidentityidentityinfo).